# How to test IIS Compression?

Tags: iis, internet-explorer, compression

I was reading the following article on how IIS compression makes the website run faster.
I have configured the IIS 6.0 in compression mode as per:http://www.wwwcoder.com/main/parentid/170/site/3669/68/default.aspx

Now I want to see some figures indicating the compression works.

P.S. I'm using IE only, because some of my components don't work on Firefox or any other browser.

How to verify (see the result) of IIS compression on IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice free tool for Internet Explorer which can be used to see if your server's http responses are compressed:

[**Fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which
>   logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your
>   computer and the Internet. Fiddler
>   allows you to inspect all HTTP(S)
>   traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle"
>   with incoming or outgoing data.
>   Fiddler includes a powerful
>   event-based scripting subsystem, and
>   can be extended using any .NET
>   language.
>
> Fiddler is freeware and can debug
>   traffic from virtually any
>   application, including Internet
>   Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, and
>   thousands more.

[image]

Here is a nice tutorial: ["Fiddler Can Make Debugging Easy."](http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/article.php/3631066)

Answer (score 4):

You can test your server's compression [here](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/).

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler and the link above work well.  In fact, fiddler is often the best option.  However, if you want an IE plug-in directly, here's a great link with various options: http://blog.port80software.com/2009/08/17/tap-tap-is-this-thing-on/.